# How to configure CAS without LDAP in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, liferay-6, cas

I just created a thread in the Liferay forum about my problem, I would appreciate it if you answered here and if possible also [there](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/100805833).

I am working with Liferay 6.2.5 CE and this is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Integrate CAS for SSO
2. On successful create a Liferay User and
3. Redirect to default private page or to the requested url
4. On logout delete the user

**Important:** Liferay is not going to use any LDAP.

I am stuck in the step two, I am not clear what I need to program or to configure. I found [this article](http://tonaconsulting.com/improving-liferay-6-cas-integration/) that seems to do what I need but it is from 2013 and maybe there is a better way to do it (not modifying directly the server files)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to modify CASFilter too in Liferay 6.2 and I think your only option is to modify server files like the tutorial says. It is not that hard